# How to get the Jenkins plugin Build User Vars to work with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, plugins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using this Jenkins plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin

With this plugin installed, if you check the box "Set jenkins user build variables", you can use the environment variable `${BUILD_USER}` which gives the name of the person who built the Jenkins job.

But, I can't get the plugin to work with the Pipeline plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin).

I noticed that checking that "Set jenkins user build variables" box adds the following line to the `config.xml` of your Jenkins job: `<org.jenkinsci.plugins.builduser.BuildUser plugin="build-user-vars-plugin@1.5"/>`

So I tried the following:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.builduser.BuildUser
echo "${env.BUILD_USER}"
```

But it prints out `null`.

Comment: I'm not fluent in groovy, but you can try to write in groovy smth like : `wget $BUILD_URL -O- | xmllint --html --xpath "//*/table/tr[2]/td[2]/p/span/a/text()" -` , which means _go to the build page, and parse to get a user_ (Note: in order to try the script xmllint and wget should be installed on jenkins host)

Answer (score 4):

try use this variable:

```
def USER = wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
     return env.BUILD_USER
}
```

I used here and It worked !!